# How can I rewrite a date field "End Date" to be "present" if no value is entered?

Tags: views, datetime

I have a `date` field for an item in which I am entering a `range of years`. I have created a view which displays the **start date and end date** as individual fields. Typical output looks like this:

> Title: Pop Art
>   Start Date: 1958
>   End Date: 1970

However, there are several items which do not have an end date because they are ongoing. Even though for the *end date* field's "No Results Behavior" I have "No results text" set to the word *present* it renders the start date in place of my rewrite text:

> Title: Contemporary Art
>   Start Date: 1970
>   End Date: 1970

I want it to do output like this:

> Title: Contemporary Art
>   Start Date: 1970
>   End Date: present

**How can I get the end date to render as the word "present" when no end date is specified?**

*Note: in my final view I will output the date range as, "1970-present." Above, I formatted my examples as "label: value" for clarity.*

Comment: are you using date module?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Date module (Drupal 7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there is no end date specified for a node it takes both the dates same. The module consider it a one day event.

However, in your case you are making it ongoing by not mentioning the end_date so no results behavior is not going to work. I would suggest to use some global php like this

```
<?php
if($row->field_date == $row->field_date_1) {
   echo "Present";
} else {
  echo $row->field_date_1;
}
?>
```

Make sure to include this php field after both start and end date fields, and make the end date fields hidden.

Comment: This got me on the right track. However *$row->field_date* returns nothing in Views PHP. I've come across this before and the solution was to use the $data variable. I will post my code as a separate answer since I can't figure out how to format a block of code in a comment.

Comment: I tried the code on my site and it was working, not sure what you messing at your end

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 2):

Shabir A.'s answer got me on the right track. However `$row->field_date` returns nothing for me in Views PHP. I've come across this before and the solution was to use the $data variable. Here's the code I ended up using (my date field is 'field_art_year' the extra `field_` is not a typo):

```
<?php
$startdate = date("Y", strtotime($data->field_field_art_year[0]['raw']['value']));
$enddate = date("Y", strtotime($data->field_field_art_year[0]['raw']['value2']));

if($startdate == $enddate) {
  print $startdate . "&ndash;present";
} else {
  print $startdate . "&ndash;" . $enddate;
}
?>
```

**Addendum**: Should wrap this code in `if (isset($data->field_field_art_year[0]) { }` or else you get errors in the log.

Comment: Addendum: Should wrap this code in `if (isset($data->field_field_art_year[0]) { }` or else you get errors in the log.