# In Views, how can I show a blank end date if no value is entered?

Tags: views, datetime

A date field in views allows you to show a start date and/or an end date. If the end date is optional, and not filled out by the user, views doesn't show a blank field if it is empty-it's show the start date for some reason.

This issue is similar to [How can I rewrite a date field "End Date" to be "present" if no value is entered?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184405/how-can-i-rewrite-a-date-field-end-date-to-be-present-if-no-value-is-entered)

I have tried messing around with the code in the above issue to meet my needs but it's not working.

I have views php installed and I need to add php code to show the field label and date but leave the date portion as blank, if empty. e.g. End Date: 2017-09-20 or if empty End Date:

These are my available variables

$row->field_start_date: Content: Position start/end date (Set to display only **start** date)

$row->field_start_date_1: Content: Position start/end date (Set to display only **end** date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I used the Views Conditional module and set it up as follows:

[image]